# how to grab specific part of a uri?

Tags: python, api, url, uri

I have a question not sure how I could search for it in the internet to find the answer. and I am at work and should solve it as much as soon posible.

I am reading URI with the following code:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Encoding': '*',
    'Accept': 'text/html',
    'Accept-Language': '*'}
import requests

link = "http://data.europa.eu/esco/isco/C0110"
f = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
print(f.text)
```

If you look at `http://data.europa.eu/esco/isco/C0110` you see that there is a descriptin for `Commissioned armed forces officers`

I need to extract just the description part.

There are thousands of line but the part that I want is this:

```
  <h2>Description</h2>
  <pre>Commissioned armed forces officers provide leadership and management to organizational units in the armed forces and/or perform similar tasks to those performed in a variety of civilian occupations outside the armed forces. This group includes all members of the armed forces holding the rank of second lieutenant (or equivalent) or higher.
```

is it possible? I have 1000 data like this so I can't do it manually. I need description part.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Try BeautifulSoup 4, https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ or python request: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ . Both can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Encoding': '*',
    'Accept': 'text/html',
    'Accept-Language': '*'}

link = "http://data.europa.eu/esco/isco/C0110"
r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
result = soup.find('pre')
text = result.text
# print whole text
#print(text)
# print just first paragraph
print(text.split('\n')[0])
```

**Output:**

```
Commissioned armed forces officers provide leadership and management to organizational units...
```

If first "pre" element isn't the description, find the description element then find the next `<pre>` element.

```
result = soup.find("h2", string="Description")
for tag in result.next_siblings:
    if tag.name == 'pre':
        text = tag.text
        print(text.split('\n')[0])
        break
```

Comment: thank you. do you know how I can get the first paragraph?

Comment: first paragraph > `print(text.split('\n')[0])`